# jsTree - rendering optimization | very long rendering with 2000 nodes

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, rendering, jstree

I'm using jsTree ( 1.0-rc3 ) with option to load data by AJAX and I have a problem with loading about ~2000 childs node by it. While server responds within several seconds, it takes jsTree about ~40 seconds only to render the results in the browser (chrome, FF). In addition to that, FF returns information about no response from 'jquery-1.7.2.min.js'.The same amount of data freezes IE. Is it overloaded with data ? Or is it some kind of bug ? Are there any changeable factors, that can help me with faster rendering ?

```
jQuery( "#dependency-tree" ).jstree(
        {
            'plugins':['themes', 'json_data', 'ui', 'core', 'types', 'sort'],
            "json_data":{
                "progressive_render": true,
                "data":initData,
                cache:false,
                "ajax":{
                    "url":function ( node )
                    {
                        return appContext + 'GetUnitsNode/'
                            + node.attr( 'id' );
                    },
                    dataType:"text",
                    "success":function ( data )
                    {
                        if ( data == "none" )
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                    }
                }
            },
            "ui":{
                'select_limit':1
            },
            "core":{
                'animation':0,
                'html_titles':true
            },
            "themes":{
                "theme":"rules",
                "dots":true,
                "icons":true
            },
            "types":{
                "types":{
                    "default":{
                        "icon":{
                            "image":appContext + "/img/orange.png"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "sort":function ( a, b )
            {
               return this.get_text( a ).toUpperCase() > this.get_text( b ).toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1;
            }
        } ).bind( "select_node.jstree", function ( event, data )
        {
            submitedNodeId = data.rslt.obj.attr( 'id' );
            submitedNodeTypeId = data.rslt.obj.attr( "typeId" );
            submitedNodeLast = data.inst.is_leaf( data.rslt.obj );
            g_node_text = jQuery( data.rslt.obj ).children().eq(1).html();
        } );
```

Comment: surely the demo of jstree if sluggish, even with 3/4 nodes... I can't imagine your experience with 2K... BTW doing it in HTML5 should be feasible. Maybe with simple class switch (folded/unfolded) and DOM manipulation as last resort

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

- [progressive_render](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)

  progressive_render
  A Boolean. Default is false.
  If this option is set to true only the visible (open nodes) parts of the returned JSON are converted to DOM nodes, any hidden parts are saved away and parsed ondemand (when a node becomes visible). This is useful when you have a large nested tree which would result in a heavy DOM
- AJAX loading