# Jstree Lazy loading with limit offset

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using jstree plugin with dynamic loading functionality and the nodes in the tree is created by the customers. So the nodes will get increased dynamically and the next time the tree loads I've to show those nodes too. The problem is each node will have nearly 50k child and its taking more time to load single node. Is it posible to append 1k by 1k into the node? My tree looks like

```
Parent
--node1
----sub node1
----sub node2
.
.
.
----sub node50k
--node2
----sub node1
----sub node2
.
.
.
----sub node50k
```

Answer (score -1):

This was the answer from the developer of jstree

> Try setting core.worker to false - it will block the UI, but it could
>   be a good 40-50% faster.
>
> Also - the best way to deal with large datasets is lazy loading,
>   jsTree also supports server-side searches, so you should not worry
>   about missing a result because of lazy loading. And even with lazy
>   loading you can still load all needed nodes in a single request using
>   the massload plugin, which means restoring state and searching will be
>   fast, but they will not require the whole dataset to be on the client.
>
> That being said, if lazy loading is not an option for you, maybe you
>   can try removing the wholerow plugin and see if that makes a
>   difference.
>
> I am afraid there is no more tips I can give you, I have really worked
>   hard on the performance of jsTree and right now I can not think of any
>   other way to speed things up, so I will close this issue. But please
>   do tell how each of the tips (aside from lazy loading) I gave above
>   affected the performance of your tree.
>
> Best regards, Ivan

Secondly I did not try, but you can try the **"progressive_render"** option from here.

[jsTree - rendering optimization | very long rendering with 2000 nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509542/jstree-rendering-optimization-very-long-rendering-with-2000-nodes)

Comment: Could you please share the link for the above post from Ivan.

Comment: I saw that post, it is rendering fast but in my case, my request takes nearly 3minutes to bring 50k nodes, so I want to break it into several requests containing fragments of child nodes and load it to the parent. I can do it for the single parent but I'm confused to do it for several parent nodes. So I need code to make several calls recursively to load fragments of data into the respective parent node repeated until the parent node is completely filled.

Comment: Not sure if pagination can help